# Ignore duplicates on insert with composite key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way to INSERT IGNORE INTO, with a composite key of certain columns?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table1` WHERE `col_a` = 1 AND `col_b` = 2;
```

Where there is a composite key of col_a_col_b.

So basically it would ignore duplicates of certain row combinations?

Right now i've made a PHP function to ween out duplicates before inserting, but it's incredibly slow. I was wondering if SQL could do it alone?

Comment: Did you forget the ending `\`` next to `table1`?

Comment: Yes it was sudo, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1(col_a, col_b) 
    select 1, 2;
```

This will insert the value pair (1, 2) every time you run it.  If you only want the pair to exist once, then you need a unique constraint.  The easiest way is with an index:

```
create unique index table1(col_a, col_b);
```

Then the above will work the first time, but fail for subsequent inserts.  By the way, for this functionality, I prefer:

```
INSERT INTO table1(col_a, col_b) 
    select 1, 2
    on duplicate key update col_a = values(col_a);
```

`insert ignore` ignores all errors.  This will only ignore errors caused by duplication -- nothing will happen and no errors will be returned.

Comment: Yes, see attached picture for what I mean, anytime an insert with those 3 column the same is attempted, it should ignore. Is that what you explained? http://i.imgur.com/80Gkp9L.png

Comment: Your question has only two columns, but the idea easily extends to three.  Yes, this explains how to ensure that certain combinations of columns remain unique in the table.

Comment: Yeah I was just saying for example. I assumed the number of columns wouldn't matter. I will give this answer a shot then because it should work, correct?